# Changing ScriptManager's attribute globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, global-asax, scriptmanager

In each projects we have several pages which have the following tag

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Now we would like to change those to (about 80% of Pages)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true"  runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Is there any way to do that from a single source like Web.config or Global.asax or using any HTTPHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an user control and placed the ajax calendar code in that. After that I replaced the Ajax calendar in the page with the user control.

Now for changing globally I can change it from the single user control.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a BasePage or a Master page then you could find the controls before the render event and modify it's properties

Comment: those pages have not basepage but a few of them have master page.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a search-and-replace regex to do this job. :)